# How do you reference external libraries with Jasmine + Resharper

Tags: extjs, jasmine, resharper-7.1, resharper-8.0

I can run Jasmine unit tests from the Resharper 8.0 unit test runner.
I have a problem where any Javascript references that are normally in the html page (ie in my case Ext-Js) then I can't use the Resharper test runner, as you don't seem to have access to the HTML page that Resharper uses. (I assume it's generated as I could not locate it on disk)

I was thinking if there is a way to call or load your external library references from the Javascript test file directly instead of via the html page, then I could get this to work. I've not found if that is possible with Javascript (or Ext-Js) yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the way to go at the moment is hardcoding include statements as special comments in the suite file (called *doc-comments references*), e.g.:

```js
// include external files like so:
/// <reference path="/path/to/external-file.js" />

// than write your testing suite as usual:
describe('a silly suite', function() {
    it('should test something is happening', function() {
        expect(something).toBe('happening');
    });
});
```

See [this thread on the ReSharper community](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/436271), as the source of this recommendation.

Comment: I saved the file locally in the project (was an external referenced file) and it worked. Is there a way to reference external files? ie path="http://server/ext-all-debug.js"

Comment: If by *external files* you mean files residing on another domain, e.g. `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1140/2.0/1140.css`, I suspect it would work the same way. give it a go and let me know if that worked.

Comment: Tried that, apparently the reference documentation only supports local files relative to the same domain. ie external files don't work. I think that's where I had my initial issues getting it to work. Copying the remote file to a local one worked as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote 2 repos for dealing with ExtJS 4 for unit testing using Karma test runner/ Jasmine 1.x and 2.0 versions and dealing with Async Issues: here they are: https://github.com/cgauthier/karma_jasmine_1_extjs4 and https://github.com/cgauthier/karma_jasmine_2_extjs4.  The trick to loading external references is to add them as files in your modules declaration.