# Referencing external script with Resharper/Jasmine/TypeScript

Tags: resharper, typescript, jasmine

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871447/how-do-you-reference-external-libraries-with-jasmine-resharper), the way to get Resharper's test runner to recognize script dependencies in your jasmine test scripts is to include them in a doc comment, like so:

```
// include external files like so:
/// <reference path="/path/to/external-file.js" />

// than write your testing suite as usual:
describe('a silly suite', function() {
    it('should test something is happening', function() {
        expect(something).toBe('happening');
    });
});
```

That's great, but I'm writing my jasmine tests in TypeScript, with a test that looks kinda like so:

```
///<reference path="../../../Scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../../Scripts/typings/sinon/sinon.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../../Scripts/Payboard/Models.ts"/>
///<reference path="../EventReferences.ts"/>

describe('Payboard.Events', () => {

var server: SinonFakeServer;

beforeEach(() => {
    Payboard.Events.setApiKey('apikey');
    server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
});

afterEach(() => {
    server.restore();
});

describe('#getAbsoluteUrl', () => {
    it('should prepend app.payboard.com to the relative url', () => {
        var absoluteUrl = Payboard.Events.getAbsoluteUrl('/some/random/url');
        expect(absoluteUrl).toEqual('//app.payboard.com/some/random/url');
    });
});
```

and when I include references like `///<reference path="~/Scripts/sinon-1.9.0.js"/>`, I get a TS compile message:

> Incorrect reference. Only files with a .ts extension are allowed.

In other words, TS doesn't let me include .js files in doc comment reference tags.

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: - did you ever get a resolve for this? Looks like R# 10 still struggles when the d.ts files are managed via nuget.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as if this is a known issue:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-389196

What they're going to have to do is add support for something like this:

```
/// <resharper_reference path="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
/// <resharper_reference path="Scripts/MyClassUnderTest.js" />
```

Chutzpah already supports this format, so it would be nice if Resharper picked those up as well:

```
/// <chutzpah_reference path="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="Scripts/MyClassUnderTest.js" />
```

The workitem says that it'll be addressed in Resharper 9.0.

It's also possible to hack up a workaround where you copy `sinon.js` to `sinon.d.js`, and then put `sinon.d.js` in the same folder where `sinon.d.ts` is located.

Comment: Very useful. I was having this problem trying to run with Chutzpah a Typescript code for Mocha. Now is solved.

Comment: From what I can tell, R# has never actually fixed this. Their suggested workaround is an ugly hack that requires you to copy the corresponding .js file to wherever the .d.ts file is located. This not only assumes that there *is* a corresponding .d.ts file, but also doesn't work when you're using nuget to manage your DefinitelyTyped definitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/sinon-1.9.0.js"/>
```

You *can't* do this in a TypeScript file as `reference` is a language feature reserved for `.ts` and `.d.ts`.

Also `'~/Scripts/'` seems wrong from the get go. Resharper will index *All* js files included in your Visual Studio project and provide you intellisence, no comments necessary.

Comment: Just to be clear - I'm not looking for Intellisense. I'm trying to figure out how to get Resharper's test runner to run my Jasmine unit tests that have dependencies on other libraries, such as sinon. When I run my tests with Chutzpah, I specify those dependencies in the page that gets loaded by PhantonJS. But Resharper runs the script directly in PhantomJS with no intermediate page, and so the only way to specify the dependencies (that I can find) is via the `///<reference path="something" />` doc comment. I know TS won't allow this - so what I want to know is - how do I accomplish this?

Comment: And `resharper` test runner picks up `///<reference path="sinon.js" /> ` ? If so does it still work after you remove `///<reference path="sinon.js" />`?

Comment: Well, Resharper's test runner is *supposed* to pick up `///<reference path="sinon.js" />`. In my testing - inserting it manually into the generated javascript - it doesn't seem to be. Not sure why. I've asked this same question on the Resharper boards - if I hear back a good answer, I'll cross-post it here.